# Empty code coverage data in GitLab CI/CD Repository Analytics

Tags: .net-core, gitlab, yaml, continuous-integration

I am using GitLab as a repository for my project and using its own CI/CD pipeline. The project is built on .NET Core and has some tests in it. Unfortunately, badge shows unknown for coverage and graph for code coverage statistics in repository analytics is empty. What am I missing?

Here is the test and coverage part of my yaml file.

```
tests:
  stage: test
  script:
    - dotnet test --logger "junit" --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
  artifacts:
    when: always
    reports:
      coverage_report:
        coverage_format: cobertura
        path: /builds/shared/project-common/tests/Project.Common.Tests/TestResults/*/coverage.cobertura.xml
      junit:
        - '/builds/shared/project-common/tests/Project.Common.Tests/TestResults/TestResults.xml'
    expire_in: 1 week
  coverage: /Total\s*\|\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/
```

This is from my Job log file:

```
$ dotnet test --logger "junit" --collect:"XPlat Code Coverage"
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /builds/shared/project-common/src/Project.Common/Project.Common.csproj (in 15.5 sec).
  Restored /builds/shared/project-common/tests/Project.Common.Tests/Project.Common.Tests.csproj (in 21.23 sec).
  Project.Common -> /builds/shared/project-common/src/Project.Common/bin/Debug/net8.0/Project.Common.dll
  Project.Common.Tests -> /builds/shared/project-common/tests/Project.Common.Tests/bin/Debug/net8.0/Project.Common.Tests.dll
Test run for /builds/shared/project-common/tests/Project.Common.Tests/bin/Debug/net8.0/Project.Common.Tests.dll (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)
Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.8.0 (x64)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Starting test execution, please wait...
A total of 1 test files matched the specified pattern.
Results File: /builds/shared/project-common/tests/Project.Common.Tests/TestResults/TestResults.xml
Passed!  - Failed:     0, Passed:     3, Skipped:     0, Total:     3, Duration: 120 ms - Project.Common.Tests.dll (net8.0)
Attachments:
  /builds/shared/project-common/tests/Project.Common.Tests/TestResults/5a580c0f-3627-4a23-811a-79a99d8859f3/coverage.cobertura.xml
Saving cache for successful job
00:08
Creating cache test-main-protected...
*/*/obj/project.assets.json: found 2 matching artifact files and directories 
*/*/obj/*.csproj.nuget.*: found 6 matching artifact files and directories 
.nuget: found 5439 matching artifact files and directories 
No URL provided, cache will not be uploaded to shared cache server. Cache will be stored only locally. 
Created cache
Uploading artifacts for successful job
00:02
Uploading artifacts...
/builds/shared/project-common/tests/Project.Common.Tests/TestResults/TestResults.xml: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=168 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_y6Jbi
Uploading artifacts...
/builds/shared/project-common/tests/Project.Common.Tests/TestResults/*/coverage.cobertura.xml: found 1 matching artifact files and directories 
Uploading artifacts as "cobertura" to coordinator... 201 Created  id=168 responseStatus=201 Created token=64_y6Jbi
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:00
Job succeeded
```